# How do I take a combobox and a textbox in one form to transfer to another form combined?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am creating a template generator and have added a sub form to add new templates vs what is already coded in. I am able to input the new template name in one Textbox and the data in a second textbox. When I hit the add button it sends the template name to the combobox on the first form like it is supposed to but it sends the data to the textbox in the first form not attached to the Template name. How do I link the two boxes when they send over?

I have done research in various websites and consulted with several books on trying to figure this out and the code I have is the closest I have gotten to figuring it out. I feel like I am only missing one link command but not sure what it is. I am reteaching myself how to use visual basic.

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form1.ComboBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    Form1.TextBox1.AppendText(TextBox2.Text)
    Close()
End Sub
```

What I am expecting to happen is when I click the button it sends the newly created template over to the combobox on form1 to add to dropdown list of Templates and be usable. What is happening is Textbox1 is going to the combobox perfectly but textbox2 is not attaching to it.

Comment: *but textbox2 is not attaching to it*. What is *it*? The ComboBox? You're appending the text of TextBox2 to another TextBox. The ComboBox is unaffected. Can you elaborate? Do you want to see the text of TextBox2 in ComboBox1, too?

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarification what I meant is when I hit the add button and Textbox1 sends to the combobox what I am trying to do is have textbox2 info combine with textbox1 info so when the info transfered to the combobox is selected the information I put it textbox 2 is what shows up as the template. for example if i put test as the template title in textbox1 and in textbox2 i type 123 when i hit add i want to have test show in the combobox and when I select it i want it to display 123 as the template.

Comment: So, you'ld like to see, in `Form1.TextBox1`, the combined information (Template Name + [Some Code]) that you see when you first add the Template name to the ComboBox (because `=> Form1.TextBox1.AppendText(TextBox2.Text)`) also when you change the selection in `Form1.ComboBox1`. You may want to use a `List(Of class)` or a Dictionary. Add these informations to one of these collections instead of directly assign the stings to the controls. You can then use the ComboBox `DisplayMember` to show the Template name and combine the `ValueMember` when you need to show the full name in a TextBox.